# Using FastMM4 in COM Objects (Delphi)

Tags: delphi, fastmm

I have used FastMM and it is a great tool to detect leaks and memory problems.
But now I try to check a COM Server made with Delphi, and the reports are not consistent.
I have tried to configure FastMM in the DLL with ShearMM and others, but I am aware that this should not be the case (the COM server must be a black box isolated from the binary that uses it, that is NOT to share the MM).
So ... How should I configure it? 
What defines should I enable in the server project so that FastMM reports leaks on the COM server?

---

EDITED

I add a delphi project as an example. It consists of a COM in-proc object with a leak and an EXE project that consumes it, also with a leak. When executing the client, only FastMM4 shows report by the client leak. Server leak is not detected (or not reported):

[Delphi Sample](https://www.dropbox.com/s/9tpz1xuwmt7b17a/FastMMComObjProblem.rar?dl=0)

A curiosity: in the server, if instead of FastMM, I use the Delphi leaks report (ReportMemoryLeaksOnShutdown), the server leak is found by Delphi!

Another clarification: my FastMM4Options.inc is untouched, as it comes in FastMM4 sources

Answer (score 0):

If you configure your COM object to run in an out-of-process server process, so that a creation of your COM object starts your EXE file, you should be free to use FastMM, isolated from the calling process as you describe.

If the EXE-file is started by COM in this way, by default it will terminate when the last object is released, unless you override this behaviour with the `ComServer.OnLastRelease` event (ComServer is declared in the `System.Win.ComServ.pas` unit).

Comment: Thanks Stijn, but I run in-proc-server (via CreateComObject function or CoCreateInstance in C++)

Comment: I have added an example to make my question more accurate (I edited my original question)